# Why can't PHP find a libpng15.so.15?

Tags: php, symfony, cloudbees

I'm running ArchLinux 64bit,  I'm trying to create a Clickstack to run [Symfony](http://symfony.com/) on [Cloudbees](https://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/Main/).

I've created a [Clickstack](https://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/DevelopingStacks) that extends [PHP-ClickStack](https://github.com/CloudBees-community/php-clickstack)
When trying to test the bundled PHP I get the following error:
`php: error while loading shared libraries: libpng15.so.15: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

I've downloaded and installed LibPng15 to /usr/local/.
I've also copied that file to: `/path/to/php/lib/`, `/path/to/php/include/`, and `/path/to/php/bin/`. It hasn't fixed the error.

I've also downloaded tried downloading the source for PHP-5.4.24 and 5.5.8 but, when I compile them they both some of the Intl tests.

So how can I get a working binary version of PHP that I can upload to Cloudbees?

Comment: did you look at what your system's LD library path is? That's where you should be dumping the .so files, not slapping it randomly all over the system.

Comment: now I feel like an idiiot. I thought I had checked that. Apprarently the solution is to just create it, set it to where my file is. (for some reason it wasn't already existant.)

Comment: @Marc B if you submit that as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to create **LD_LIBRARY_PATH** as an environment variable in script.
Apparently it didn't exist.

`LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib:/usr/local/lib/:/path/to/libpng/`

**NOTE:** adding the normal directories prevents other tools/apps from breaking.